# OpenSource OCR Software for MAC for pulling numbers out of a JPG

Tags: open-source, ocr, jpeg

What is best OpenSource OCR software out there for Mac or from a website (I guess Perl and Ruby are probably okay as well) for extracting numbers out of a JPG in the following format:
http://www.whnt.com/extras/whnt/weather/7day_640.jpg

It would be best if no gui were required and it could be run from the command line.

Thanks for any information and feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/). People have been able to compile and get it to run on OS X.

Comment: Do you have any additional info on Tesseract running on OSX?  I see the following statement on their website: "Additionally, we believe that the code should be running on these other platforms", but no additional details are provided.  Thanks again.

Comment: quick google gives: http://www.malcolmhardie.com/ocr/index.html

Comment: Poke around its Wiki pages. Quite a few people claimed successful compiling on OS X.
http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/w/list